# Suggestions for mastering a sound FX library?

Tags: sfx, sound-effects, library-sound-effects, mastering

I want to put together a sound fx library which will have some processing.  I'm wondering the best way to master the effects so they all have the same timbre and overall level. Is this typically done or do you just bounce out each effect and group them at some point regardless of how well they fit together?  Any advice on these last stages would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

this is a pretty good starting point for you: http://www.jetstreaming.org/2012/09/05/an-introduction-to-sound-effects-mastering/

Once you have read that article explore the rest of the jetstreaming blog, as a lot of it will be useful info for what you are tackling.

Comment: @AzimuthAudio Thanks for the mention, Timothy :)  @reznor I'll be adding more articles about mastering and curation in the future, and if you have any questions feel free to shoot me a PM.

Answer (score 0):

I am putting together a sound effects library myself. If I had to recommend a good resource it's the book I just bought: *sound effects bible*. pretty good stuff in there. There's also a few resources online I like but the largest and most encompassing is http://www.epicsound.com/sfx/index.php

Of course I've also created a channel for foley sound effects, http://www.youtube.com/user/DIYFoley

Each week (every saturday) I'll be creating a new slew of effects for my audience. I've been doing tons of research and experimentation so who knows you may find that to be a nice reference/guide in the near future, why not subscribe?